Convert word document to pdf with clickable links
I have the following code that converts a word document named LG_LINKS.docx to pdf with clickable links. The code is working but the links not accurate. For example I have this link https://streamable.com/remj but when I click on it in the output pdf I got other characters at the end of the link like that `https://streamable.com/remj%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%81%D9%8A%D8%AF%D9%8A%D9%88%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%AB%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%AB%D8%AA%D8%B3%D9%83%D9%8A%D9%86%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%81%D8%B5%D9%88%D9%84%D9%88%D8%AA%D8%B9%D8%AF%D9%8A%D9%84%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%84%D8%BA%D8%A9%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%A3%D9%88%D9%84%D9%89%D9%88%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%AB%D8%A7%D9%86%D9%8A%D8%A9ذ
from docx import Document
from docx.shared import RGBColor
from docx.oxml.ns import qn
from docx.oxml import OxmlElement
from docx2pdf import convert

def make_links_blue(docx_file):
    doc = Document(docx_file)
    for paragraph in doc.paragraphs:
        for run in paragraph.runs:
            if 'https' in run.text:
                url = run.text.strip()
                run.clear()
                hyperlink = OxmlElement('w:hyperlink')
                new_run = OxmlElement('w:r')
                rPr = OxmlElement('w:rPr')
                color = OxmlElement('w:color')
                color.set(qn("w:val"), '0000FF')
                rPr.append(color)
                underline = OxmlElement('w:u')
                underline.set(qn('w:val'), 'single')
                rPr.append(underline)
                new_run.append(rPr)
                text_element = OxmlElement('w:t')
                text_element.text = url
                new_run.append(text_element)
                hyperlink.append(new_run)
                run._r.addnext(hyperlink)
    doc.save(docx_file)

def export_docx_to_pdf(input_docx, output_pdf):
    try:
        convert(input_docx, output_pdf)
        print(f'PDF Created Successfully: {output_pdf}')
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print(f"Error: The File '{input_docx}' Was Not Found.")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"An error occurred: {str(e)}")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    input_docx = 'LG_LINKS.docx'
    make_links_blue(input_docx)
    output_pdf = 'LG_LINKS.pdf'
    export_docx_to_pdf(input_docx, output_pdf)


No Problem. I just need working links.
